# Java Order of Operation

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I am having some problems understanding stacks and order of operations in java. If I had the following:

```
operation(7, 2)

public int operation(int x, int y) {
    if (x == y)
        return 0;
    else
        return operation(x – 1, y) + 2;
}
```

What would be the result? I am being told that it should be a single number result but I don't understand how (x – 1, y) + 2 can be single number. I have gotten it to:

```
(x – 1, y) + 2
(7 - 2, 2) + 2
(5, 2) + 2
```

But I don't understand the method for adding the 2 at the end. Wouldn't this need to return both values separated by a comma?

Comment: Do you mean "single digit" rather than "single number"? It has to be a single number result, because the result is int. (I don't see why it would be single digit, either)

Comment: The recursive formula is effectively `2*(x-y)` where `x >= y` (not defined if x < y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wouldn't this need to return both values separated by a comma?

Nope.

`operation(x – 1, y) + 2` is a recursive function.

`operation(7 - 1, 2) + 2` => `operation(6, 2) + 2` This calls the `operation` function with arguments 6 and 2 (similar to how you did the initial call). This call will eventually end up with a number to which 2 is added and returned.

Taking a smaller number for better visualization `operation(4, 2)`

```
operation(4, 2) -> return operation(3, 2) + 2
operation(3, 2) -> return operation(2, 2) + 2
operation(2, 2) -> return 0 (the base case)
.. stack unwinds
operation(3, 2) -> return 0 + 2
operation(4, 2) -> return 2 + 2
```

Comment: Thank you. Recursive programming is something am having a difficult time grasping.

Answer (score 1):

```
operatation(7, 2) returns -> 8 + 2 = 10
   operatation(6, 2) returns -> 6 + 2 = 8
       operatation(5, 2) returns -> 4 + 2 = 6
          operatation(4, 2) returns -> 2 + 2 = 4
             operatation(3, 2) returns -> 0 + 2 = 2
               operatation(2, 2) returns -> 0
```

The recursive calls will be made till the x and y values equal, in that case `operation` returns `0`. The return value is then added to `2` and returned to caller i.e. `0 + 2 = 2` and so on, till the first caller is returned. Hence the answer is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

This ends up being roughly equivalent to a `for` loop, actually. This code has the exact same result as `operation(7, 2)`:

```
int equivOfOperation = 0;

for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)
{
    equivOfOperation += 2;
}
```

The recursive function will end up doing the equivalent of

```
for (int i = y; i < x; i++)
```

assuming, of course, that `y < x`. (In this case, `operation` would end up with infinite recursion).

Since several of the other answers have already shown the trace of the recursion, I won't repeat that here, but you might want to walk through their traces and convince yourself of this having the same effect as a `for` loop.